# Mobile Application Network Requests Logs

Tags: networking, logging, mobile, splunk, appdynamics

I am after some help.

I have a mobile application that I would like the ability to log all network requests made to our internal APIs.

For our websites we use Splunk to log all network activity and this is great for doing investigations. my issue is that I need to engage with other teams to get these logs to do my investigations. We have App Dynamic, but this doesn't give me what i want.

For example. we might have an issue with users not being able to log into out sign on API. I would like to be able to have a tool that would allow me to tack the user in question and see what was sent to the API and what the response was.

Could you please let me know a tool that would help me with this? is there a way to create a server that all requests pass though, that i could install Splunk on? is there a better approach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

AppDynaics logs every network request and crash if you implement the mobile component. Did you test the Mobile components for AppDynamics?

Comment: We have the Mobile Component added. the issue i have is we only se the response code and nothing more. I ideally need to be able to see the request and the response code + the data. this would allow me to identify  individual customers and pin point their issue and resolve.